# how can I connect an IP cammera via ethernet to my Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: raspbian, networking, camera, dhcp

I have an IP camera that I want to connect to my raspberry pi 3 using an ether net cord. I have struggled with this reading many articles, trying to configure the camera to have a static IP recieved from a local dhcp server. At one point it was almost working... but not now (yeah it was my fault, I changed some stuff and now it doesnt work.)

I have isc-dhcp-server installed. The camera is connected to the ethernet port via an Ethernet cable. I want to assign the camera, and the raspberry pi  static addresses using ipv4.

Here is my dhcp.conf:
ddns-update-style none;

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

# A slightly different configuration for an internal subnet.
subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.42;
#  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
  option domain-name "local-network";
  option routers 10.0.0.1;
  option broadcast-address 10.0.0.254;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
}

host fantasia {
# hardware ethernet 08:00:07:26:c0:a5;
  hardware ethernet c4:d6:55:3e:4e:72;
  fixed-address 10.0.0.5;
}
```

and here is my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual
#iface eth0 inet static
address 10.0.0.7
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255


allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

what am I doing wrong? Have tried rebooting, the camera and the Pi. how can I set a static network between these devices using only  an Ethernet cable?

Comment: Do you mean directly connecting the 2 devices directly by Ethernet cable, after assigning static IP addresses? Or will there be a router/switch somewhere in between? Direct connections would require a crossover network cable.

Comment: Direct connection is what I am trying. I think the cross  over cable is not required on modern chipsets. I had it working with out one. I did make a crossover cable as well though. I can retry it.